# How to block specific URL instead of whole domain

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, url

I am looking to block a specific url like:

```
http://foobar.com/abc.php
```

instead of the whole domain of

```
foobar.com
```

I have tried to edit the host file by adding an entry

```
127.0.0.1 foobar.com/abc.php
```

but it didn't work. Tried restarting the data too.

Can anyone tell me what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

i'm sorry to tell you, it wont work.

In the hostfile you can only set an IP-Adress of an domain manually.
For example:
I dont want that my pc always looks for IP-Adress for ilovethis.net.

Or a better one:
I have many photos, videos and audio on my homeserver. But i dont want to always type 192.168.178.178 (etc.) in my Browser. 

Yes! I would add an entry to my hostfile which says: Domain home.server should go to 192.168.178.178 (looks like: 192.168.178.178 home.server)

I hope you know what i mean.
This was not made for specific url,
its for local DNS manipulation.

Greetings,
Fischmaster

Comment: Actually on windows it works perfectly. Just by adding the url on windows PC that particular URL is blocked but on android its not working.

Comment: Yes, of course. But i dont known if it even works in whole Linux.